# swift Multiple video playing in UITableViewCell depends on Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, video, uiscrollview

Hi I am trying to make some application.

that is this application (i can't upload video in stackoverflow.. so i linked my blog and uploaded video)

http://blog.naver.com/cooksunghun/220488172371

like this application.

there are multiple video in tableview.

but play video is in only one talbleViewCell

I tried and i made tableViewCell and embed video. but i can't function that play only one part depends on scroll... (i am new about progmraming T_T)

I tried with scrollViewDidScroll and VisibleCells

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let cell = VideoCell()
    let visibleCell = tableView.visibleCells 
    var count = visibleCell[0]
    switch count {
        case visibleCell[0] : cell.playVideo()
        case visibleCell[1] : print("test2")
        case visibleCell[2] : print("test3")
        case visibleCell[3] : print("test4")
        default : print("testDefault")
    }
}
```

i hope someone give idea. Thanks you!
(sorry for bad english)
i am waiting your idea!

Comment: If i am doing very bad or wrong, i hope you give some hint :) Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late but you are on wrong way. You don't need `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods, only thing you need this methods from `UITableViewDelegate`;

```
- tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

For what? According to Apple docs;

> A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses
>   cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the
>   cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a
>   chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table
>   view, such as selection and background color. After the delegate
>   returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame properties, and
>   then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.

So, according to scroll direction while your next cell will prepare to display, this method firing and you need to prepare your video content to play in this method.

```
- tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

For what? According to Apple docs;

> Use this method to detect when a cell is removed from a table view, as
>   opposed to monitoring the view itself to see when it appears or
>   disappears.

So, according to scroll direction, while your cell which one is last seen will preparing to destroy. Meanwhile, your next cell will be preparing to display. You need to prepare to stop your video content here. You didn't give any information about your video content class which could be `MPMoviePlayerController` or `AVFoundation` so search for how to prepare your video content to stop and play.